# Rename domain cause empty page

Tags: php, .htaccess, file, url, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rename my domaine via htaccess fom http://old.com/page to http://new.com/page , in the first page http://new.com/ working fine, but when I want to go to other page I have 2 problems:

1. the the url not changed they have always the some text , like :
   http://new.com/
2. the rewriting of page does not working until I
   add .php like this : http://new.com/page.php

this is my htaccess code :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)  http://new.com/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.*)$  http://new.com/$1 [R=301,NC]



RewriteRule ^page$ page.php [QSA,NC]
```

I'm really have no idea about this :(((

Comment: Do you want to redirect your entire old site to the new or just some specific pages?

Comment: i just want rename my domaine from http://domaine1.com to http://domaine2.com

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I think you don't need to add `/` in your `RewriteRule ^/(.*)  http://new.com/$1 [R=301,NC]` line.

Try this and let me know (I havent tested it) :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)  http://new.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
# -----------^-------- the change is here
```

This should redirect any page from `old.com` to the same page on `new.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#redirect "olddomain.com/" to "newdomain.com/"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://new.com/ [R=301,L]
#rewrite "olddomain.com/page" to "olddomain.com/.php"
RewriteRule ^page$ page.php [L,NC]
```